# Passing in directive ng-model to uib-tooltip

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to create a custom directive to generate inputs for an `ng-form` and these inputs should be able to show a tooltip with information in it based on what errors are currently within the given field.

The issue I have is with trying to get the tooltip template to be able to read the `ng-model` of the custom directive to see when the field it goes with is `$invalid` or not to show either a green check mark or a specific form error message. But it seems the `ng-model` in the directive is not updating it's `$invalid` value when the field contents change.

https://plnkr.co/edit/sBKZgaGzFZtAz5Ntl2FD?p=preview

I have put together a basic plunker with the directive and some dummy data to illustrate. I expect that when I backspace all of the content out of the input, the required invalidation should cause the content in the tooltip to show true instead of false since the invalidation should be false now.

If someone can help me make sense of this that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Going through your example, I found issues in multiple places:

**1)**
In the `import-input` directive, the correct attributes to check max and min length is `ng-minlength` and `ng-maxlength`.

**2)**
in the `index.html` you should wrap the `import-input` directives inside a `form`. This is crucial for the next issue and is generally a good idea for proper validation.

**3)**
When checking if the input field is invalid, i found that going to the `$$parentForm` property of `ctrl` shows the correct value for the valididty fo the field. The form object has a property for every child element, whose propery name is the same as the `name` attribute. Since you are dynamically generating the `name` attribute when creating the element, you can use this same variable to address the element from the `$$parentForm`. Setting the scope to invalid would look like this:

`scope.invalid = ctrl.$$parentForm[elementName].$invalid`

I've added a working plunker with these changes, forked from your version:
**https://plnkr.co/edit/Ja7Wxqq6KWOk1IXXr7U0?p=preview**